# C#, Win Server, TFS - Custom dependencies libraries

Tags: c#, tfs

i have a question. In my company we solved how to access to our project libraries (dll or js libraries). Where you saved your libraries? It is possible save to TFS server and simple add reference to project? or exist something analogy as nuget for company (local network)? thanks for your opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a private NuGet feed - either a HTTP server or simply a network location - and use it internally in your company. (You can also use a managed service like MyGet that provides private feeds if you're not concerned about your packages being hosted outside.) See [the NuGet docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/overview) for more info.

Comment: Thanks it is correct! But exists any free solution?

Comment: [NuGet.Server](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Server) is a free and open source solution. Keep in mind that you can also simply add a local (or network) folder as a NuGet package feed out-of-the-box without having to install anything.